# $f(\lambda)$ eigenvalue of $f(A)$ always implies that $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix over the field $\mathbb{F}$. If $f(A)$ is the polynomial matrix given by the ansatz
$$ f(A)=\sum_{j=0}^k a_j A^j ~~(k\leq n ~~~\&~~~a_k \neq 0).$$

It is rather obvious that in case that $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair of $A$ implies that $(f(\lambda),v)$ is an eigenpair of $f(A)$.

---

**Is the converse implication also true?** (i.e. $f(\lambda)$ eigenvalue of $f(A)$, implies $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$)? Comments and suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general result:

> If $F$ is algebraically closed field or $A$ is triangularizable, then $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$ iff $\mu=f(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

See a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2785540/if-a-is-an-eigenvalue-of-ft-then-a-fc-for-some-eigenvalue-c-of-t).

Comment: Is this result closely related with the proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Just take $A=\text{diag}\{1, 1\}$ (i.e. the identity matrix) and $f(x) = x^2$. We have that $f(-1)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A) = A$, though $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. So, one needs to impose that the polynomial $f(A)$ is non-singular to ensure that $f(\lambda)$ eigenvalue $f(A)$ implies $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$. Is it right?

Comment: @NelsonFaustino you’re welcome; I do not understand what you mean by “non-singular” **polynomial**

Comment: Non-singular means $f(A)v=0$ implies $v=0$ ($\ker f(A)=\{0\}$).

Comment: @NelsonFaustino now that makes sense. Well no, in this case $f(A)$ was actually non-singular

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true. Suppose that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1,$ that has $n+1$ district roots.

Then $|f^{-1}(\lambda)|=n+1$, but $A$ has at most $n$ eigenvalues.